# Multiple Language IDE

Tags: ide, text-editor

I've been using Notepad++ for years and although it is comfortable I am feeling the need to move up into the IDE world for various reasons, which I'll outline below. I am looking for IDE recommendations for someone who works in multiple languages on a daily basis - I am currently looking at Eclipse and Netbeans but willing to consider any option.

The reason I have not made the switch to a full-fledged IDE yet is because they feel so bloated, they are slow to load and eat up a ton of memory. Recently, I have been working on an astronomical number of projects (5-6 at work, upwards of 10 personally) in a variety of languages (Python, PHP, Ruby, Java, Javascript, xHTML, CSS, TorqueScript to name a few). These are just the languages I am using on a daily basis - although I don't expect to find an IDE that will meet all the demands of these languages (especially the more obscure TorqueScript on the list).

So, what would you recommend for someone who needs a fast, configurable IDE that offers support for a variety of languages, syntax highlighting (preferably with various color schemes), project organization/browsing, Intellisense-ish code completion?

I forgot to mention I am primarily targetting the Windows environment here - when I'm on my Xubuntu machine (minimally) Geany works fine for what I need to accomplish.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388/best-ides-for-different-programming-languages

Comment: @seth: Not really, that question refers to independent IDEs for each language whereas I am looking for the best solitary solution for multiple languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend Eclipse as the closest match for the multi-language requirements. There are IDEs that possibly shine better for a given language (e.g. I prefer IntelliJ for Java), but none that have such a broad coverage of multiple languages.

As far as memory/bloat, it's a price you pay for the convenience that an IDE provides.

Answer (score 4):

The [Zeus IDE](http://www.zeusedit.com) is pretty much *language neutral*, meaning it can be easily configured to work with almost any programming language.

It also has a lot of [IDE like](http://www.zeusedit.com/features) features (i.e project/workspace management, class browsing etc), yet still feels snappy and responsive like a light weight text editor.

Comment: Works well enough for all my c/c+= coding. The auto complete is not always correct but it works well enough and at least it is as fast editor.

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is kind of the Swiss Army knife of the programming world... With plugins, it'll handle pretty much any language you throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/) covers Java, Ruby and PHP which are on your list. It's definitely a bit bloated though, and I understand your pain there.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs.

Seriously.

Comment: Sorry for my trivial question, but are you for serious ? :)

Comment: It starts up and runs fast, has name-completion, syntax highlighting, a killer regexp builder, great key-bindings, column editing, macro support, inline spell and syntax checking, the ability to create/resize/change windows with the keyboard, can pipe text through a shell command and then replace the original text, and it has tetris!

Comment: Vim also does editing, the same way as emacs... Without the bloat, and it can also do all of that if you want...

Comment: Vim doesnt have butterfly mode

Answer (score 0):

With those requirements, the closest you're going to get is Eclipse.

You might also want to check out [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/). It won't offer you all of the features you are looking for, but it should be a hell of a lot faster than working through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried a web based one? [Koding](http://koding.com?c=ideh) covers a whole pool of languages and above all that you get a free VM with root access. Definitely worth checking out.